# Alternative of MaskFull for a text box?

Tags: vb.net

For Microsoft Visual Studio, what's an alternative I can use for the MaskFull of a text box?

```
If txtVehicleNumber.MaskFull = False Then
    MsgBox("Enter your Vehicle Number in the Vehicle text box", "Error")
    txtVehicleNumber.Clear()
    txtVehicleNumber.Focus()
    InputError = True

' Example code:
If txtStudentID.MaskFull = False Then
   MsgBox("Enter your Student ID in the Student ID box", , "Error")
   txtStudentID.Clear()
   txtStudentID.Focus()
   InputError = True
```

Comment: Why do you want an alternative? Please explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `MaskFull` is a member of the `MaskedTextBox` class.  If you're saying - without actually saying - that you want the same thing for a standard `TextBox` then you're out of luck because there is no such thing.  There's no mask so how could it be full?  If you're trying to validate a `TextBox` then you need to consider what the actual requirements for valid data are and test for them.  If you are trying to make sure that the `TextBox` isn't empty then test for that.  You don't need a dedicated property.  Apply some logic.

Comment: I'm trying to make sure that the text box is not left empty. I was hoping to know what I can use in place of MaskFull or if there is any other alternative method I can use to ensure the user does not leave the text box blank.

Comment: I've added in an example code. Instead of MaskFull, what example logic can I use in its place for the txtVehicleNumber?

Comment: [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider) Class

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool:

> MaskedTextBox
>   And  properties; PasswordChard =